# Android SQLite returns stale data after altering table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

We are experiencing a strange bug with Android SQLite: When we create a database, close it, reopen it, add columns and query e.g. the number of columns again, we get the old value.

We are using quite the latest built tools and target SDK version (33). Here is a short test that demonstrates the problem:

```kotlin
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.*
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper
import androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SmallBugTest {

    private val TEST_DB = "small-bug-test"
    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
    private lateinit var db: SupportSQLiteDatabase

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        //The bug doesn't seem to appear if everything is done is one session (at least with this suite), so let's simulate two sessions
        /* Database is created */
        SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration(context, TEST_DB,
            object : SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback(1) {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) = createDb(db)
                override fun onUpgrade(
                    db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                    oldVersion: Int,
                    newVersion: Int
                ) = throw AssertionError()
            }).let { FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory().create(it).writableDatabase }.close()

        /* Database is closed, e.g. the app has been closed */

        ////////////////////////////////////////////

        /* Database is opened, not created */

        db = SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration(context, TEST_DB,
            object : SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback(1) {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) = throw AssertionError()
                override fun onUpgrade(
                    db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                    oldVersion: Int,
                    newVersion: Int
                ) = throw AssertionError()
            }).let { FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory().create(it).writableDatabase }
    }

    private fun createDb(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE `TEST_TABLE` (" + //
                    "`column0` TEXT NOT NULL," +
                    "`column1` TEXT NOT NULL" +
                    ")"
        )
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO `TEST_TABLE` (`column0`, `column1`) VALUES ('content0', 'content1')")

        db.version = 1
    }

    @Test
    fun causeBug() { //If this test is successful, the bug occurred
        db.query("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE").close()

        modifySchema(db)

        db.query("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE").use {
            it.moveToFirst()
            assertArrayEquals(
                arrayOf("column0", "column1"),
                it.columnNames
            ) //Should be ["column0", "column1", "column2"]
        }
    }

    private fun modifySchema(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `TEST_TABLE` RENAME TO `TEST_TABLE_OLD`")
        db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE `TEST_TABLE` (" + //
                    "`column0` TEXT NOT NULL," +
                    "`column1` TEXT NOT NULL," +
                    "`column2` TEXT" +
                    ")"
        )
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO `TEST_TABLE` (`column0`, `column1`) SELECT `column0`, `column1` FROM `TEST_TABLE_OLD`")
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE `TEST_TABLE_OLD`")
        db.update(
            "TEST_TABLE",
            CONFLICT_NONE,
            ContentValues().also { it.put("column2", "content2"); },
            null,
            null
        )
    }
}
```

This is what we have already found out: A query is dispatched to the `(Support)SQLiteDatabase` a matching `PreparedStatement` is returned by [`acquirePreparedStatement`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/bcf722f0e722337bc2b919996f6b46acf572b27d/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java#1055) and then executed. `acquirePreparedStatement` either creates a new PS and then caches it in the `PreparedStatementCache mPreparedStatementCache` or returns a previously cached PS. A PS matches if it was created by exactly the same sql text (adding backticks or a comment will cause a new PS to be returned accordingly.)
Some operations on the cursor for a query (e.g. `Cursor#getX`) will always be populated with fresh data **for every call** to `query`, but some operations like `getColumnCount` or `getColumnNames` will only be populated **once per PS** (or more precisely: They always seem to be [populated with the data from the time of creation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/bcf722f0e722337bc2b919996f6b46acf572b27d/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java#679) of the PS.)

Accordingly if a query is dispatched and cached *and then* the table is changed to have more columns *and then* a query with the same sql text is dispatched, the resulting cursor from the second query will use the same PS internally and return correct content values for the new columns, but will still report the same (now outdated!) `columnCounts` and `columnNames`.

There's also an issue in the Google bug tracker where we've noted our findings but haven't found a workaround yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153521693#comment18

Have you encountered this problem and found a workaround?

We created this sample project if you want to see it in action: https://github.com/SailReal/Android-Issue-153521693

Answer (score 0):

when altering the database schema in SQLite, such as adding columns or modifying existing ones, you should also increment the database version.

when you increment the version number and implement the necessary changes in the onUpgrade() method of your SQLiteOpenHelper subclass

for your code solution

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SmallBugTest {

    private val TEST_DB = "small-bug-test"
    private val DATABASE_VERSION = 2 // Updated version number

    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context

    private lateinit var db: SupportSQLiteDatabase

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context.getDatabasePath(TEST_DB).delete() //Clean up last test

        /* Database is created */
        SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration(context, TEST_DB,
            object : SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback(DATABASE_VERSION) { // Use the updated version number
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) = createDb(db)
                override fun onUpgrade(
                    db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                    oldVersion: Int,
                    newVersion: Int
                ) = throw AssertionError()
            }).let { FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory().create(it).writableDatabase }.close()

        /* Database is closed, e.g. the app has been closed */

        /* Database is opened, not created */
        db = SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration(context, TEST_DB,
            object : SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback(DATABASE_VERSION) { // Use the updated version number
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) = throw AssertionError()
                override fun onUpgrade(
                    db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                    oldVersion: Int,
                    newVersion: Int
                ) = throw AssertionError()
            }).let { FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory().create(it).writableDatabase }
    }

    // Other methods remain the same...
}
```

Below is general solution

```
 import android.content.Context
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    
    class MyDBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    
        companion object {
            private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 2
            private const val DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.db"
        }
    
        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your initial database schema here
            // This method is only called when the database is first created
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")
        }
    
        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            // Handle database schema upgrades here
            if (oldVersion < 2) {
                // Add new columns or modify existing schema
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN age INTEGER")
            }
            // Handle other version upgrades as necessary
        }
    }
```